# how to render partials in custom templates in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, pdf

I am having some pdf templates in app/pdfs/templates/work folder and in each of them some of the code is repeating and I want to add a partial with this code and render it in the templates.

I added parrtial in app/pdfs/templates/_calculation.html.erb:

```
<td class="money last footer-subtotal">
    <p><strong><%= sub_total %></strong></p>
    <p><strong><%= total_tax %></strong></p>
    <p class="footer-total"><strong><%= final_price %></strong></p>
</td>
```

In template i used :

```
<%= render "templates/calculation" %>
```

When I click on pdf, i am getting the following error:

**undefined method `render' for #**

Comment: I've not worked with PDFs before - how are you outputting them into the view?

Comment: Or how to write the above code in helper method

Answer (score 1):

Partial reads on app/views.

Instead of putting your partial on:

`app/pdfs/templates/`

Put inside of views:

`app/views/pdfs/templates/`

Comment: I did the same and gave            ` <%= render "/pdfs/templates/calculation" %>` , but same error.

Comment: Remove `'/'` before pdfs. And be sure that it is under app/views. (app/views/pdfs/templates/_calculation.html.erb) Then you can call it as: `<%= render 'pdfs/templates/calculation' %>`

Comment: It didn't helped me. Same issue

Comment: You have to use `render partial`. `<%= render partial 'pdfs/templates/calculation' %>`

Comment: Did you already locate your `_calculation.html.erb` to `app/views/pdfs/templates/` directory or it is still under `app/pdfs/templates` directory?

Comment: Added _calculation.html.erb in app/views/pdfs/templates/ folder and i use  it in app/pdfs/templates/work.html.erb `<%= render partial 'pdfs/templates/calculation' %>`